# How to test PACKAGE_REPLACED event

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I'm trying to catch .PACKAGE_REPLACED event in order to see if my code runs good, however I can't simulate it. I tried using adb shell command:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED -n com.draoid/.com.draoid.installationtracking.nnn.InstallTracking --es "package_replaced" "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That `Intent` is protected and can only be sent by the system itself. However, if you
reinstall your app using

```
adb install -r yourapp.apk
```

This should generate the `PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast.